# Question on proving $\lim_{x\to\infty}\pi(x)/\frac x{\log x}=1$

Tags: analytic-number-theory

I want to prove that $\lim_{x\to\infty}\pi(x)/\frac x{\log x}=1$, where $\pi(x)$ is the number of primes less than $x$.

Let $\psi(x)=\sum_{p\leq x}\log p$. It is stated that I only need to show $\pi(x)-\frac{\psi(x)}{\log x}=O(\frac{x}{(\log x)^2})$ as $x\to \infty$.

I wrote down explicitly what big O notation means, but I have trouble seeing why this is so. Specifically, I'm not sure about the speed of increasing of $\psi(x)$ as $x\to \infty$. Could you give me any insight? Thanks!

Comment: First you have to show that $\psi(x) \sim x$ as $x\to +\infty$. You can see that it is equivalent to the original statement on $\pi(x)$.

Comment: That makes sense, thank you. ~ notation means that the ratio as $x\to \infty$ is 1, right? Is there a way to handle big O notation better without actually computing it (by diving and showing that the ratio is bounded)?

Comment: Is big O notation something I should remember and use when necessary?

Comment: It was shown that there exists a positive constant $c$ such that $\psi(x)=x+\mathcal O\left(xe^{-c\sqrt{\log x}}\right)$

Comment: @jk001 In this case it is helpful to use little o notation so that $\psi(x)=x+o(x)$

Comment: Thank you so much @TravorLZH Just as a follow-up on big Oh notation.. how do I understand or handle it better? To my naive mind, it just looks like extra work... In the above case, once I get $\psi(x)$~ $x$, I think I can directly compute the result without the intermediate step of using big O notation.

Comment: @jk001 Yeah, that's why I said little o notation comes in handy when we only know $\psi(x)\sim x$.